# How to View Slack Payload Body Content in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, slack-api

So I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get back a payload from Slack when using interactive messages. I send a message with buttons. I have everything set up properly, Slack is hitting my return URL just fine.

The problem is I don't know how to retrieve the "payload" from the request? Slack documentation says:

"Your Action URL will receive a HTTP POST request, including a payload body parameter, itself containing an application/x-www-form-urlencoded JSON string."

I guess I have no idea what this means. I thought it meant you get a POST Variable of "payload", but that's not what happens.

In Laravel I'm using the following to try and get something back:

```
$request = Request::all();
$test = Response::json($request);
```

And then I'm sending this to myself to take a look at and the results are as follows:

```
object(Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)#277 (10) {
  ["jsonOptions":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["data":protected]=>
  string(2) "[]"
  ["callback":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["encodingOptions":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["headers"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag)#332 (5) {
    ["computedCacheControl":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["no-cache"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["cookies":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["headerNames":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cache-control"]=>
      string(13) "Cache-Control"
      ["date"]=>
      string(4) "Date"
      ["content-type"]=>
      string(12) "Content-Type"
    }
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cache-control"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(8) "no-cache"
      }
      ["date"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(29) "Thu, 22 Jun 2017 04:51:13 GMT"
      }
      ["content-type"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "application/json"
      }
    }
    ["cacheControl":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["content":protected]=>
  string(2) "[]"
  ["version":protected]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["statusCode":protected]=>
  int(200)
  ["statusText":protected]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["charset":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

There is no "Body Parameter" no "Payload" variable. I'm really confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Slack is sending back a POST request with contains a payload parameter in its body. I am not familiar with the Laravel framework, but here is how I receive it in plain PHP:

```
$payload_json = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'payload', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
$payload = json_decode ($payload_json, true);
```

After that the `$payload` parameter contains an array with the request content.

If I understand your code correctly (first 2 lines) you are trying to interpret the whole request as JSON, which will not work. You need to first extract the payload and then decode that from JSON to a PHP object.

However, I would suggest to first make sure you receive the Slack request at all at your action URL by logging the content of each request you receive (e.g. by logging the content of `$_POST`)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, whenever I tried to just use:

    $payload = Input::get("payload")

Which would get any GET or POST variable, it was always empty and I couldn't figure out why, which is why I tried to pull the entire response, and I'm not seeing a Payload variable being sent there either. I'll try tinkering around with your information and apply it to Laravel.

Comment: hmm. are you sure you are receiving a request from Slack at all? It does not sound like you do. btw. you can also use `$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');` to get the complete raw body from a POST request.

Comment: Well maybe not I guess? But why does Slack hit my webhook with an empty request? If there was something wrong wouldn't they send something like an error? Or wouldn't they just not hit it?

Comment: IN my experience. if somethings goes wrong with the interactive message, the user who clicked on the button gets an error message in Slack

Comment: you can also simulate the Slack request to your "webhook" to see if that one works. [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/)

Comment: Yeah I don't know how the Slack Request looks which is why it is so hard to pull it apart to use it. Like in the hurl.it example you can set parameters or body. According to Slack documentation it uses the body, it doesn't set parameters. Since I only know how to retrieve the parameters I figured that was my issue, but again it's a bit outside of my experience.